# No changes to FrameLayout is made when adding and removing views

Tags: c#, android, mono, xamarin.android

I have an activity. I load the layout using **setContentView(R.layout.myLayout);**

and it loads my layout as usual. Now I have a FrameLayout that I want to add controls to it and remove them at some point. When I change the background color, it works but when I change LayoutParameters, when I add views or remove them it never changes anything in the app. Why? I never had this problem before.

Here is my code.

```
findViewById<FrameLayout>(R.Id.dropzone1).RemoveAllViews();
```

Then events for adding child and removing them is fired but actually it doesn't work.

I really appreciate if somebody helps. I'm stuck at it and I have no idea what is wrong here.

Comment: What are the properties of the items you're adding?  They could be invisible, or they might need a call to requestLayout, or they might have margin that pushes them out of the frame, or the frame might have  padding that pushes them out.  It would help to have more context on exactly how you're adding the views to the Frame layout.

Comment: I can add more details on what I'm adding (a Button with fill_parent as width and height) but why RemoveAllViews() is not working then? I have Button in it (added in the resource file) but it is not being removed.

Comment: I copied my code into another project and it worked just fine. I really don't know what caused that silly problem but it is working in the new project.